# Yii2- Run Console app on windows using Scheduler

Tags: php, controller, background, yii2

I am working on `yii2`. I have a create function which I want to run in the background after every 24 hours.

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new MeterPing();

    // CURL code to get results from web-api

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Also in this function, I will be fetching some records from a `web-API`. But my main concern is to run the above function in the background after every 24 hours.

**Update 1**

As per suggestion was given I have created a controller in `console\controller`

```
namespace console\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {

public function actionIndex() {
    echo "cron service runnning";
}}
```

Now, for testing it I followed this [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2) and created a run service using `cmd` with following parameters

[image]

Now, by following as per suggested I have tried each step. The `.bat` file contains

```
@Echo off
title My Cron Job
:: See title at the top
php E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\yii test
pause
```

After saving the file and adding it to the task scheduler. I tried to run it from this interface. And I did see a cmd opening and showing the message.

How can I do it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: create a cronjob as in the answer below

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The given link is for linux but i want it for windows. Though I have created a testing cronjob but still I am unable to make it run after every minute.

Comment: is it the local system where you are trying to setup the cron ?

Comment: yes for now i am using local system

Comment: added an answer see if that helps you out

Comment: can you mark this answer as correct

Comment: Bro I haven't yet tried it. I will definitely do it after finishing the latest issue.

Comment: sure take your time i thought you forgot :D

Comment: :D no no i will give it a try later

Comment: If you see the first **`NOTE`** I added **make sure you have `php` in [`Windows Path Variable`](https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/) or you should provide the complete path to php.exe in the above `.bat` file**, which isnt in your case . you havent added `php` in your windows path variable, as you are running php executable using `e:\xampp\php\php` looking at your command prompt screenshot, you should provide the complete path to php in the `.bat` file which you havent, go through the instructions carefully, it is a working solution. unless you are missing something.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have already followed the steps which you have told me. I have provided `windows path variable` and created a `.bat` file. By using `task scheduler` I tried to run it and it did show me a `cmd` and the `echo` text in it. But now I am facing another issue I want to call an `action` from another controller via my `console controller` but I am unable to get any result. For this I have already updated my question. Kindly see Update 2

Comment: that is a separate question and does not have to do anything with this scheduler, you might have to add a separate question.

Comment: remove the Update 2 from your question and add a separate question for that.

Comment: Ok let me add new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Task Scheduler for windows

- Create a `.bat` file which should contain the command for running your Yii console app `controller/action` if you create a controller class `TestController` that extends `yii\console\controller` and add a `create` action, to run that action from Yii console application you would type `./yii test/create` on the project root using gitBash or console, so we will add this command to `.bat` file by providing the full path to the `project_root/yii` which is the Yii console bootstrap file. This is the main thing to run the job as part of Yii controller action code.

open notepad and copy below code in it an save as `.bat` with name `my-cronjob.bat`

```
@Echo off
title My Cron Job
:: See title at the top
php F:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\yii test/create
pause
```

**NOTE: make sure you have `php` in [`Windows Path Variable`](https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/) or you should provide the complete path to `php.exe` in the above `.bat` file**

#### Steps to create a Task Scheduler

- Type in Task Scheduler in the start menu and open it.
- **Create a basic Task**

[image]

- **Write a name for the task**

[image]

- **Select Trigger time `Daily`**

[image]

- **Select time to execute the task**

[image]

- **Select `Action` Start a programme**

[image]

- **Now select the `my-cronjob.bat` file and press Next and Finish**

[image]

- **Now go to task manager and select `Task Scheduler Library` and right click the cronjob you just created and open properties.**

[image]

- **Select `Run with highest privileges`**
  [image]

*NOTE: you can select to run the cronjob if the user is logged in or not, by default it only runs if the user is logged in you can change that option.*

That is it now you can either manually run the task by right-clicking and selecting run and it will run the desired `controller/action` specified in the `my-cronjob.bat` or wait for it to trigger on the specified time.

#### For running in the background

The above settings will open the command prompt and run the task if you want the scheduler to run the task minimized you should see this [**`link`**](http://blog.kikicode.com/2011/10/run-minimized-batch-file-in-task.html) and update the task settings accordingly. Also, you can change the last line `pause` to `Exit` too.

**I have tested it before posting the answer here as I have `Windows10` OS at my home, so couldn't post the answer without testing from office.**

Comment: Thank you, bro. I'll definitely give it a try

Comment: I would have to create a console app first then make a bat file that will call that console app??

Comment: Or I have to just make a bat file and call my controller ?

Comment: @MrFaisal your console app is the folder console that is already there, you have to create bat file , and a controller inside the console app, as mentioned

Comment: your controller should be in `console/controllers` and extended from `yii\console\Controller`

Comment: Ok. I have a controller named `MeterpingController` which `extends Controller`. In this controller, I have a create function. I want to call this function automatically. So I have to call my create function in my `console/controllers` like `MeterpingController::Create()` ?

Comment: I have created a new controller name `CronController` which extends from `yii\console\Controller` and inside it I have an `Index` function and I am calling my create function of `meterping` controller like `public function actionIndex() {
        Yii::$app->runAction('meterping/create');
    }`

Comment: As always @muhammad-omer-aslam beautiful solution. nice :clap:

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are looking for a [cronjob](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-running-cron-services--cms-27508).

You'll have to create a console cronjob and then add it to your crontab on the server. The above link has a wiki on how to set this up for Yii2.

Example crontab which will run every day at 3 PM:

```
0 15 * * * /var/www/project/yii daemon/create
```

Comment: I have created a sample `crob job` by following this [tutorial](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2#create-console-application) but here it's not mentioned how to run it after some time interval. The link you have given is very helpful in creating a job but it's for linux and i want it for Windows

Comment: Read up on cronjobs. A cronjob is specifically designed for this

Comment: I have read the cronjob. It says to use `Task Scheduler` for windows. I have tried to make cronjob scheduler but I didn't see any output over the console