# Unable to run console app on windows azure

Tags: azure, cron, console-application, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2`. I have created a `cron` service and via console app, I am calling it. Below is my code

```
namespace console\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {

public function actionIndex() {
    echo "cron service runnning ";
}

public function actionMail($to) {
    echo "Sending mail to " . $to;
}

}
```

By following one of the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50163032/8919244) I am able to make things work

**Console App Code**

```
@Echo off
title My Cron Job
:: See title at the top
php E:\xampp\htdocs\yii test
pause
```

I have deployed this console app in my local(Windows 10) and testing machine(Windows Server 2012 R2). And in both the app works fine.

**Output (Local and Testing Machine)**

[image]

But when I try to apply the same method in my `azure windows` The output I am getting is

[image]

It doesn't display the message `cron service running`.

**Environment Variable (php)**

[image]

I have followed the same steps as mentioned in the solution. But I don't know why it's not working on my cloud.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: as far as i know on microsof zure you have the azure scheduler or may be i am not getting you right

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam bro I am trying to run the console inside the azure windows. And it's windows 10. If I try to run the `.bat` file directly it doesn't show me the `echo` string.

Comment: Seems the composer is not installed in your Windows Azure.