# Yii2 Console command scheduled execution

Tags: php, yii2

Is there any mechanism through which yii2 console command can be scheduled to run at a specific time, with ability to check if the previous job has ended or not.

Comment: You can use [Yii2 Queue](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-queue/doc/guide/2.0/en/usage)

Comment: And what Operating System are you using?. Linux? Use Cron. Windows? Use Scheduled Tasks. There are many examples of this. F.e.: https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-running-cron-services--cms-27508

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148807/yii2-run-console-app-on-windows-using-scheduler